# VueJS application is not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm new to VueJS. I have initial files i.e. index.html and index.js(I should not add more files).

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Password strength indicator</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/all.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="app" class="container">
       <h1>Vue Password Strength Indicator</h1>
       <label class="frmLabel" for="password">Password</label>
       <input placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" class="frmField" 
        type="password" @input="" v-model="password" />
        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' : message.length > 
         7}">
        <i class="frmIcon fas" :class="message.length > 7 ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"> 
        </i>
        Longer than 7 characters
        </p>
        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' :has_uppercase }">
        <i class="frmIcon fas" :class="has_uppercase ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i>
        Has a capital letter
        </p>
        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' :has_lowercase }">
        <i class="frmIcon fas" :class="has_lowercase ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i>
        Has a lowercase letter
        </p>
        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' : has_number }">
        <i class="frmIcon fas" :class="has_number ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i>
        Has a number
        </p>
        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' : has_special }">
        <i class="frmIcon fas" :class="has_special ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i>
        Has a special character
        </p>
        </div><!-- #app  -->
        <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({
   data() {
     return {
     password: '',
    };
   },
  computed: {
    message() {
      return this.password.length > 7;
    },
    has_uppercase() {
      return /[A-Z]/.test(this.password);
    },
    has_lowercase() {
      return /[a-z]/.test(this.password);
    },
    has_number() {
      return /\d/.test(this.password);
    },
    has_special() {
      return /[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]/.test(this.password);
    }
  },
});

app.mount('#app')
```

The problem is that, the content of the application is not rendering i.e. the content of `<div id="app"></div>.`

I have following warnings in console:

[Vue warn]: Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js".
at

and

Feature flags **VUE_OPTIONS_API**, **VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS**, **VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS** are not explicitly defined. You are running the esm-bundler build of Vue, which expects these compile-time feature flags to be globally injected via the bundler config in order to get better tree-shaking in the production bundle

Comment: based on your project setup, vue is unable to compile and detects that you need to use a different build of vue.  see the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling#note-on-in-browser-template-compilation).  try `import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';`

Comment: if you're brand new to Vue, and you're not sure how to begin, it's recommended to use the scaffolding tool to make a fully runnable project from scratch.  again, see the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application).  you would just need to run the command `npm create vue@latest`

Answer (score 1):

Loading a DOM element as the template of your Vue app requires runtime compilation.

Most Vue applications are developed and run without the need to use runtime compilation ***<sup>1</sup>***, using the esm bundler version of Vue, because runtime compilation modules are fairly large compared to the rest of Vue. Those projects use single file components (`.vue`), which are compiled at build time.

You have two options:

- enable runtime compilation - replace `import { createApp } from 'vue'` with
  `import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'`
  Note this will unnecessarily increase Vue's bundle size.
- use SFC's (recommended):

**index.html:**

```
//...
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
//...
```

**src/index.js:**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**src/App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    ...rest of template...
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  data: () => ({
    password: ''
  }),
  computed: {
    // computed here...
  }
})
</script>
```

For best experience and results, I wholeheartedly recommend following [Quick start](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start) instructions.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - runtime compilation is mainly purposed for incremental adoption of Vue (replacing only parts of an existing web page, compiled at runtime), which is not needed in your case.